# Invalid jQuery Format - 2D Array

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to organize my projects into a json file. Firefox gives me "XML Parsing Error: not well formed ... Line Number 1, Column 1".

I would like to access my projects' data as a 2D array. If I want the 1st col 2nd row project, I would access it as jsondata.projects[1][2].

This is how I structured my json file which has two columns, three rows in the first, and two rows in the second.

```
{
"projects" : [
    [
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
  ]
}
```

When I try to access this json file from the console of Firefox, I am given the error.

Comment: Please add you'r error log

Comment: https://hastebin.com/axihebateq.bash

Comment: If you want the 1st col 2nd row you must write `jsondata.projects[0][1]`, because array start at 0 in JavaScript.

Comment: Okay. I tried jsondata.projects[0][1] and I get the same XML not well formed error for line 1, column 1. In the console, before the error, and after the command I issue, an object is returned which is the entire json file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

If I call `jsondata.projects[0][1];`, I am returned the whole json object then the XML Not Well Formed error for Line 1 Column 1.

However, if I call `console.log(jsondata.projects[0][1]);`, then I am returned the entire json object, then the element of the json I want! I am still given the XML Not well formed error.